# Downloading WideVine/FairPlay protected content for offline playback via Azure Media Services

Tags: exoplayer, azure-media-services, widevine, fairplay

I have developed a mobile application for iOS/Android that I would like to enable offline playback on so users can download content and watch on a plane, etc... for up to 1 month after download.  This content needs to be protected from users downloading for further distribution. When reviewing Azure Media Services' documentation (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/offline-widevine-for-android) they mention that ExoPlayer supports offline playback for protected content.  ExoPlayer supports offline playback but it does not appear to support it for protected content, any downloadable content with the WV prefix does not actually appear to be protected by WideVine as there is no drm scheme / drm license url.

Does anyone know of examples of players capable of protected WideVine/FairPlay offline playback and how it implements the license/manifest file being used together?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Media Services supports offline mode for both Widevine protected DASH for Android and FairPlay protected HLS for iOS.

For FairPlay/HLS protected offline mode, Apple provides a sample code in their FPS SDK. The detailed instructions and sample can be found in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-protect-hls-with-offline-fairplay

For Widevine/DASH protected offline mode, ExoPlayer SDK can be used. Here is our doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/offline-widevine-for-android

Comment: ExoPlayer SDK demo only supports downloading unprotected content for offline playback.  The docs you have referenced above (I have reviewed them multiple times) do not provide a demonstration of how to play the downloaded file locally and use the generated license key to decrypt.  Please elaborate where in these docs you see the example of offline playback being used on protected content or if you know of any public examples that would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: For Widevine protected offline case, Google does not provide an end-to-end example, so certain development effort is required.

Comment: Thank you for the response @William Zhang - can you provide an example URL of how to download a manifest file for MPEG-DASH or HLS for offline playback that has been encrypted.  After reviewing all of the documentation and doing research on 3rd-party platforms I haven't been able to come across that yet.   If I can get the file downloaded I already have the license key generated so it should be pretty straight-forward from there.

Comment: I only have a couple of samples for HLS/FairPlay offline download https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/CHT#22. I don't have one for DASH.

Comment: Also a correction: Google does provide a complete DASH/Widevine protected offline mode sample, but it is for Android Chrome, not for ExoPlayer: source code https://github.com/googlearchive/sample-media-pwa and hosted version: https://biograf-155113.appspot.com/ttt/episode-2/

Comment: I tracked down how to create the progressive download URL from the streaming endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure//media-services/previous/media-services-rest-get-started#creating-a-sas-url-for-downloading-content).  However I can not figure out how to decrypt the asset with its' bearer token from this URL (example: https://willzhanmswest.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/8d078cf8-d621-406c-84ca-88e6b9454acc/20150807-bridges-2500_H264_1644kbps_AAC_und_ch2_256kbps.mp4) so that I can download it for offline playback.  Currently receiving a 403 auth error on my URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get offline playback working for my Azure hosted widevine content, using the hosted shaka player demo: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/

Check out this tutorial too: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-offline.html

Comment: ShakaPlayer is awesome, but do you know where it is downloading the file to for offline playback and how it is retrieving the adaptive bitrate progressive download URL from the manifest file?  I see the table in my chrome local storage with the file details but not the actual file location.  Thanks for your assistance Brian!

Comment: I doubt you need to know/care about that level of implementation, but I think the shaka experts are responsive to their issue tracker: https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll take a look - I am trying to build an iOS/Android protected offline playback implementation so unfortunately I need to get into the details.